# Требуется пояснение No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте,объясните следующее:
почему надо прописывать `Class.forName("com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.Driver");`?
Ведь здесь написано [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/connector-j-fabric-connect.html)

> Note If you are using Java 5, you must manually load the driver class
>   before attempting to connect.
>
> Class.forName("com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.Driver");

Но ведь у меня же 8,что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это зависит не от версии Java, а от JDBC. В JDBC 4.0 появилась автозагрузка драйвера DBMS через механизм [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) (SPM).

Когда вы запрашиваете соединение, `DriverManager` через ServiceLoader сканирует classpath и ищет файлы `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`, после чего загружает все перечисленные в них классы. Вот, например, содержимое этого файла в драйвере MySQL:

**META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```

Чтобы не полагаться на поддержку SPM конкретным драйвером, можно зарегистрировать его вручную через `Class.forName()`.

В версии драйвера MySQL 3.x.x SPM не поддерживается, т.е. драйвер необходимо загружать вручную.